# Find $i\log(x-i)+i^2\pi+i^3\log(x+i)+i^4(2\arctan x)$, if $x>0$

Tags: complex-numbers

> Find $i\log(x-i)+i^2\pi+i^3\log(x+i)+i^4(2\arctan x)$, if $x>0$

The equation can be written as $$y=i\log(x-i)-\pi-i\log(x+i)+2\arctan x$$
$$y=i\log\frac{x-i}{x+i}-\pi+2\arctan x$$
Let $x+i=re^{i\theta}$ so
$x-i=re^{-i\theta}$.
$$y=i\log(e^{-2i\theta})-\pi+2\arctan x$$
$\theta=\arctan\frac{1}{x}=\cot^{-1}x$
$$y=2\cot^{-1}x-\pi+2\tan^{-1}x=2\cdot\frac{\pi}{2}-\pi=0$$

Is this correct?

Comment: What happened after the second last step?

Comment: $i\log(e^{-2i\theta})=i\cdot -2i\theta=2\theta$

Comment: Maybe this relation between the complex logarithm and the arctangent is useful here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1102389/arctan-in-complex-logarithm-form

Comment: Yea, then? How $4\arctan...$

Comment: oops. I made a mistake.

Comment: I think you should first rationalize $\frac{x-i}{x+i}$ and then use $\text{Log} z=\ln|z|+i\text{Arg} z$

Comment: @AdityaDev There is a difference between logarithm of real numbers and logarithm of complex numbers. Do you know that?

Comment: Consider the polynomial in $a$: $a\log(x-a)+a^2\pi+a^3\log(x+a)+a^4(2\arctan a)$.

Comment: Why should I make the problem more difficult @Aditya Agarwal ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last step is wrong.

Please note the following:

If $x+i=re^{i\theta}$, then $\theta=$ arg (x+i) = $\arctan \frac{1}{x}=arccot x$

So,

> $$i\log(e^{-2i\theta})-\pi+2\arctan x$$
>   $$=i(\log|1|+(-2i\theta))-2(\frac{\pi}{2}-\arctan x)$$
>   $$=i(\log|1|-2i\theta)-2arccot x$$ $$=2arccot x-2arccot x$$ $$=0$$

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Assume $x\in\mathbb{R^+}$:

$$y(x)=i\ln(x-i)+i^2\pi+i^3\ln(x+i)+i^4\left(2\arctan(x)\right)=$$
$$i\ln(x-i)-\pi-i\ln(x+i)+1\left(2\arctan(x)\right)=$$
$$i\ln(x-i)-\pi-i\ln(x+i)+2\arctan(x)=$$
$$2\arctan(x)-\pi+i\left(\ln(x-i)-\ln(x+i)\right)=$$
$$2\arctan(x)-\pi+i\left(\ln\left(\frac{x-i}{x+i}\right)\right)=$$
$$2\arctan(x)-\pi+i\left(-2i\text{arccot}(x)\right)=$$
$$2\arctan(x)-\pi+2\text{arccot}(x)=$$
$$2\left(\arctan(x)+\text{arccot}(x)\right)-\pi=$$
$$2\left(\arctan(x)+\arctan\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)-\pi=2\left(\frac{\pi}{2}\right)-\pi=\pi-\pi=0$$

So:

$$y(x)=2\left(\arctan(x)+\text{arccot}(x)\right)-\pi=0\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\space\text{with}\space\space x\in\mathbb{R^+}$$